# How to Parse a specific string in C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have this structure:

```
{
   "longUrl" :"http://www.sample.com",
   "bok" :1,
   "url" :"http://pleasegetme.com ",
   "title" :""
}
//equivalent
    "{
       \n   \"longUrl\" :\"http://www.sample.com/\",
       \n   \"bok\" :1,
       \n   \"url\" :\"http://pleasegetme.com \",
       \n   \"title\" :\"\"\n
     }"
```

I have this function

```
public string Domain1Helper(string longText)
{
    Regex rgxUrl = new Regex("\"url\":\"(.*?)\"");
    Match mUrl = rgxUrl.Match(longText);

    string url = Regex.Replace(mUrl.Groups[1].Value, @"\\", "");
    return url;
}
```

What I want to get is `http://pleasegetme.com`.

What is the wrong in my `Domain1Helper` method?

Comment: That is a JSON string. Use a json deserializer.

Comment: no, just a string.

Comment: @AJB - yes it is "just a string", but a string containing data in JSON format.

Comment: Regex is slightly wrong. You forgot the space in '"url" :'

Comment: @kumarch1, I rollback your edit. The OP is not aware it's a JSON (so adding comment into question "it's json string" is wrong edit). I also change formatting, while you didn't. Pay attention to "was changed" warning when you are editing next time please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJB, You have an error in your RegEx.
That being said you should use a JSON deserializer, like JSON.NET.
In the function Domain1Helper it should be:

```
Regex rgxUrl = new Regex("\"url\"\\s+:\"(.*?)\"");
```

Notice the \s+ ?

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a JSON string. You can parse this using a library called [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). You can find this as a nuget package. You can then use the following code to pick out the strings you want.

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(longtext);
Console.WriteLine(jo["longUrl"].Value.ToString()); // Outputs 'http://www.sample.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a freaking JSON formatted string. Use a JSON deserializer such as JSON.NET. I'll leave it to you on which one you'd want to use.

Here is the root object generated using json2csharp.com

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string longUrl { get; set; }
    public int bok { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

Example using JSON.NET:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; // Namespace is something like this


string json = "{
                 \n   \"longUrl\" :\"http://www.sample.com/\",
                 \n   \"bok\" :1,
                 \n   \"url\" :\"http://pleasegetme.com \",
                 \n   \"title\" :\"\"\n
               }";

RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
string url = rootObject.url;
// Do something with the url
```

Answer (score 0):

You have included the escape strings `\`. If you remove those, it should parse just fine, as in here:

https://regex101.com/r/hK7xR7/1

Note, that you method should look like this:

```
public string Domain1Helper(string longText)
{
    Regex rgxUrl = new Regex(@"\"url\" :\"(.*?)\"");
    Match mUrl = rgxUrl.Match(longText);

    string url = Regex.Replace(mUrl.Groups[1].Value, @"\\", "");
    return url;
}
```

And alternative solution would be using one json library, which is outlined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197957(v=vs.95).aspx